# I have a issue with Order By in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-apex

I having this issue when I try to retrieve data from two tables.

DEPT Table

[image]

EMP Table

[image]

I want to use this query

```
SELECT EMP.ENAME, DEPT.LOC, EMP.SAL
FROM EMP, DEPT
order by DEPT.DEPTNO;
```

but it's creating the data with all locations in table DEPT

DATA

[image]

Comment: if you can  show the tables in the question itself it would be much easier for the ones that are trying to answer

Comment: what is your expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your query is doing a `CROSS JOIN` which creates all possible combination of two tables. As `DEPT` table has 4 rows and `EMP` table has 11 rows then it will create total 44 rows as a final result.

Instead you should do this

```
SELECT 
    e.ENAME, 
    d.LOC, 
    e.SAL
FROM EMP e
JOIN DEPT d
on e.DEPTNO = d.DEPTNO
order by d.DEPTNO;
```

Comment: I think Join not working in APEX " ORA-00904: "E"."DPETNO": invalid identifier "

Comment: There was a `typo`, I have edited it. please try again